# Can't get post_ID inside wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make my first WP plugin, but stuck on simple function - can't get ID of post inside it.

I have tried:

```php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

After that I thought, that my plugin works outside loop and try this:

```php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

Few hours later I have tried to create function, that get post id after INIT:

```php
function postidfinder () {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    return $post_id
}
add_action( 'init', 'postfinder' );
```

Also tried actions: wp_loaded, loop_query.

Please, help get post ID to the plugin. Thanks!

Comment: What is the context of the plugin file where you are attempting to get the post ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, to use post->ID outside of loop, wp_query should be called first.

```
global $wp_query; 
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Optionally, `get_post_id()` can work for you, check codex for more.

**From the Global $post object :**

Global object $post contains a lot of data of the current post. It is very easy to get ID from the object:

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

**Using get_the_id() and the_id() functions:**

The difference between this two functions is that get_the_id() returns ID of the current post, and the_id() prints it.

```
echo get_the_id();
the_id();
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not work. My plugin is almost empty, but can't get post ID, variable send NULL

Comment: Add few line of code or just plugin code with function and action so I can check.

Comment: include 'classes/test.php';



function postid_head(){
 global $post;
 $postid = $post->ID;
 global $postid;
 return $postid;
}
add_action('admin_head', 'postid_head');


 if ( ! is_admin() ) { // If Frontend, load file
         $id = $postid;
  // other code
 } else {
 }